# Floating hint textbox does not show up correctly

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a textbox with the following AXML code:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
  <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Gebruikers naam"
    local:MvxBind="Text UserName"
    android:singleLine="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The problem is that if the text box is filled on startup(which happens when someone has logged into the app before) the text box shows up like this:

[image: Screen]

But it has to show up like this:

[image: Correct way]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This seems to be a known issue with TextInputLayout: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230171

Comment: @Cheesebaron O well I'm trying to see if a delay might work since I've got another screen which get filled when I press a button. But on that screen it works fine. So it seems like it is because it gets filled before it's completely loaded. Or is this a false observation